# Git - Change tracking configuration of branches

Tags: git, remote-branch

I have the following branches (local and remote):

```
origin/master
origin/alter
origin/alter_old
master
alter
alter_old
```

If I do `git branch -vv` I get:

```
master     6aec3b5 [origin/master] blam
alter      8c32a03 blaa1
alter_old  1669af7 [origin/alter: ahead N, behind M] blaa2
```

I want `alter` to track `origin/alter` and `alter_old` to track `origin/alter_old`. How can I do it? I tried the following:

```
git checkout alter_old
git branch -u origin/alter_old
```

but I get:

```
error: unknown switch `u'
```

And the same for `--set-upstream-to`.

EDIT: Strangely, I think that when I push, `alter`pushes into `origin/master` and `alter_old` pushed to `origin/alter_old`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For git 1.8.0 onwards**

```
git branch alter_old -u origin/alter_old
```

**OR**

```
git branch alter_old --set-upstream-to origin/alter_old
```

**For git 1.7.0** : Use `--set-upstream` instead of `--set-upstream-to`

```
git branch --set-upstream alter_old origin/alter_old
```

Comment: `git branch <BRANCH> -u origin/alter_old` returns `-bash: BRANCH: No such file or directory`. `git branch alter_old -u origin/alter_old` returns the same `error: unknown switch 'u'`. And exactly the same for set-upstream-to.

Comment: which version of git are you using?

Comment: use `--set-upstream` and don't use `BRANCH` literally. I mean use `alter` in place of BRANCH. eg `git branch --set-upstream alter_old origin/alter_old`